# Re-enable password autocomplete for CP login

Tags: login, admin, password

Since [ExpressionEngine 2.5.3](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-5-3) the form used to log into the control panel has `autocomplete="off"` set on the password input field. This means that browsers won't offer to remember passwords when they're entered.

When creating new passwords for super-admins I [generate a long, unique passwords using Keychain](http://www.macworld.com/article/1145804/passwordassistant.html). I'll never remember these, and there's no way my clients will either. Because of this, I always recommend that people have their browsers remember passwords. I believe this is in every way more secure than remembering the password (i.e. writing down on a sticky note somewhere) and entering it (i.e. having it read by a keylogger) every time.

**My question is:** can the `autocomplete="off"` attribute be removed from the password input field somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these instructions from the EllisLab forum:

> You can just create your own CP theme by copying the file found at /system/expressionengine/views/accounts/login.php to /themes/cp_themes/my_theme/accounts/login.php and editing it to your liking. Now when you choose that theme instead of the default theme, EE will use your file instead. For all the files not found in your theme, EE will fall back to the default theme’s files.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/227881/#1035125

Comment: Thanks! Just got this working.

For anyone reading in the future, the file you want to edit is actually `/system/expressionengine/views/account/login.php` (not "accounts"). You also need to copy the `/themes/cp_themes/default/images` directory and place it in your new custom theme. That theme only needs the files you want to edit as mentioned above. The only downside to this I can see is that if the CP theme updates with new functionality, you won't get that unless you also update your modifications manually.